# replace an instance by a variable

Tags: java, variables, replace, instance

How can I make a user input to let the user select which Cook has to prepare the food?

In LINE33 `deliverer1.delivered(cook1, customer);` cook1 is a fixed instance, but it better should be a kind of variable to represent either `cook1` or `cook2`

```
class DamascusShoarma {

   static int Cooksnumber;
   static int Deliverersnumber;

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Cook cook1 = new Cook("Jan de Vries", "Slagersmes 1", "1212-IS",
            "Allahmelo", 123456);
      Cook cook2 =
            new Cook("Sinbad", "Kameelbult 2", "2323-IS", "Halal-lem", 654321);
      Deliverer deliverer1 = new Deliverer("Ali Baba", "Helmgras 11", "3434-JH",
            "Ji-Hattem", 456789);
      Deliverer deliverer2 = new Deliverer("Muammar", "Zadeldreef 22",
            "4545-JH", "Moskemenade", 987654);
      Customer customer = new Customer("Piet Hein", "Maagdenburglaan 5",
            "5656-KL", "Darmstadt");
      cooksnumber = Cook.Cooksnumber;

      deliverersnumber = Deliverer.Deliverersnumber;

      deliverer1.delivered(cook1,
            customer); /*
                        * Line 33 the line that matters to my question. cook1 is
                        * a fixed instance. How can this be a kind of variable
                        * so that it could also represent cook2 if wished???*
                        */
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to store the cooks you have in some data structure and then look through that data structure to find the cook by a given search criteria, e.g. `HashMap<String, Cook>` and then call `get(cookName)` on it or put them into a `List<Cook>` and iterate over the list and check each cook if he matches the search criteria.

Comment: @luk2302, Thanks I will figure that out. But what will need to be put instead of `cook1` in the line 'deliverer1.deliverd(cook1, customer` can that be a declared variable for it? or what kind of value does it need over there?

Comment: @user85421, yeah it's not a fixed instance indeed. But I meant, it's fixed as it has been written in 'deliverer1.delivered(cook1, customer)'  as a fixed value.

Comment: @luk2302, thanks I did IT!!! it works with HashMap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to select the cook, you'll need to get that from a UI or use the arguments.  Then you could use the advice of @luk2302 to set the variable.  For example (sample code only) using the first argument as the cook's name:

```
class DamascusShoarma {

    static int Cooksnumber;
    static int Deliverersnumber;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ... Set delivers, customers etc...

        Cook cook1 = new Cook("Jan de Vries", "Slagersmes 1", "1212-IS",
            "Allahmelo", 123456);
        Cook cook2 =
            new Cook("Sinbad", "Kameelbult 2", "2323-IS", "Halal-lem", 654321);

        Hashmap<String, Cook> cooks = new Hashmap()<String, Cook>;

        cooks.put(cook1.name, cook1);
        cooks.put(cook2.name, cook2);

        Cook cook = null;
        if (args.length > 1 && args.args[1] != null)
        {
            cook = cooks.get(args[1]);  // This is the answer to the question
        }
        // TODO Error check in case cook == null

        cooksnumber = cook.Cooksnumber;  // Used here

        // TODO - do something similar to cooks to select the deliverer
        // and customer
        deliverersnumber = Deliverer.Deliverersnumber;

        deliverer.delivered(cook, customer);  // And here.

    }
}
```

Comment: you also thanks. You put me in the right direction in solving the problem. Thanks for your helpful contribution!!!

Comment: Welcome.  Good luck!

Comment: btw..shouldn't it be `put` instead off `add`??

Comment: Right you are.  Fixed the post.